# Automatic conversion of C++ API to C#?

Tags: c#, c++, winapi

I am wondering if there is something like automatic conversion/wrapper code generation of a c++ API to C#?

Specifically I am seeking a way to call the Remote Desktop Services API from C#.

Comment: Is it really a C++ API, or just a C API? For C++ look into SWIG. For a c API check http://clrinterop.codeplex.com/releases/view/14120

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might try either decompiling RDCMan (http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21101), it does it. Or there is an open source project on Codeplex that does it as well.

http://terminals.codeplex.com/

EDIT:

There is also a tool that Microsoft provides call aximp (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ccdh774(v=VS.100).aspx). If you run aximp.exe {{path_to}}\mstscax.dll, it will generate a .NET WinForms control library that wraps the ActiveX control.

Comment: I am now using the Terminals project, it had all the interop code I need. Thanks for your help!

Comment: c:\windows\system32\mstscax.dll is a ready-to-use ActiveX control.

Answer (score 3):

A suggestion: C++/CLI. 
Using the C++/CLI you can use the libraries written in C/C++ to C/C++ along with of the .net libraries/dll's. More information:
[A first look at C++/CLI](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/mcpp/cppcliintro01.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

No you definitely need to create an interop code.
If it's a COM api there is some sort of support for using it directly with C#